# Cordova not recognized as external command inside project folder?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I have cordova installed in my npm folder. After cd Project_name in command line and tying `cordova add platform` i am getting an error

> `"Cordova is not recognized as internal or external command"`

. I don't know what is wrong is here. I followed each step given on cordova documnentation. Below is a screenshot of the error

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can't see the screenshot and what was the command you used to install cordova ?

Comment: npm install -g cordova this command. I am able to create project but after cd project its giving error @warl0ck

Comment: a shot in dark but have you tried restarting your command prompt and/or reinstalling by `npm install -g cordova`

Comment: Yes , Several times i even restarted my PC

Comment: did you get any information/error/warnings after installing it ?

Comment: No It installed correctly. I am also able to create project . But not able to ren cordova inside cordova folder.

Comment: so you are able to create project with cordova ? like `cordova create myApp` ?

Comment: Yes I am able to create project

Comment: in that case cordova is installed on your system, problem is somewhere else

Comment: are you able to use npm inside your project folder ?

Comment: Yes i am able to access npm inside project folder

Comment: Thanks for your help I solved the problem. I downloaded the a.zip for node.js . Once i run the .msi  installer i worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check everything you have installed:

```
node - v
cordova -v
```

if these are not installed then, install it first.

Download and install NodeJS from here: https://nodejs.org/en/

Then check again `node -v`

If you have installed node successfully then install cordova.

```
npm install -g cordova
```

and then check `cordova -v`

I suggest that you will take a tour of getting started with cordova: http://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted

Comment: everything is installed . I am even able to crate project using cordova . Its just that i am not able to access cordova inside project folder

Comment: What do u mean by not able to access Cordova inside project folder ??

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the cordova using:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

After this you will able to add the platform.

Comment: Thats exactly what i did. @Shubham Bhardwaj

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352527/cordova-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: This is not helping. According to you i have not installed cordova correctly but then if that was the problem then how am i able to create project

Comment: Have you tried setting path for Node? May be this can be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't set Environment Variable for the node JS.

Please follow steps which are provided in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352527/cordova-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command).

Answer (score 0):

1. delete "platform" folder
2. Try add re-platform :

   npm install -g cordova

or

3. Try reinstalling the cordova using:

   npm install -g cordova

Answer (score 0):

The Below steps helped me out:

Install Cordova using: npm install -g cordova

1. Check if Cordova is installed:  To check go to "C:\Users\your username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules" and search for Cordova folder. If it does not exists then in CMD run 'npm install -g cordova' to install cordova or reinstall npm and run 'npm install -g cordova'.
2. Environment variable PATH Exists: To check go to Environment variable (My Computer OR My PC  > Right Click  > Properties > Advance System Settings > Environemnts Variable button)
   add
   %appdata%\npm\ or c:\users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm
   (replace YourUserName with the name of your user profile)  to System Variable's PATH

Below are the screenshots step by step actions on Environment PATH.

[image]